# How to improve the robot frame rate when using motion planning in rViz?

Tags: ros, motion-planning, rviz, moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there,

I am currently trying to get a better **frame rate** for the motion planning plugin in **rViz**. Right now, I have a frame rate of 1 or 2 Hz. Another user had the same problem, which looked like this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2yPOtkc84M&feature=youtu.be. His solution was to increase the **joint_state_publisher** rate (https://answers.ros.org/question/307723/how-to-make-robot-movement-in-rviz-with-moveit-smoother/), but in my code, I only use my own moveIt "robot"_planning_execution launch file, which loads multiple launch files (like robot_interface_simulator.launch, planning_context.launch and move_group.launch) and a robot_state_publisher node. Also, if I load a robot model in rViz, the frame rate is way faster than the motion planning plugin.

So my question is, how do I increase the frame rate for the motion planning plugin in rViz if I don't use a joint_state_publisher?

I am using kinetic with rviz version 1.12.17.

Thanks,

Julien Audet

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333229/how-to-improve-the-robot-frame-rate-when-using-motion-planning-in-rviz?/) by [Julien Audet](https://answers.ros.org/users/40390/julien-audet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2019-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can set it programmatically with :

```
rviz::Display moveit_display = rviz_manager_->createDisplay("moveit_rviz_plugin/MotionPlanning", "motion_planning", true);    
moveit_display->subProp("Scene Geometry")->subProp("Scene Display Time")->setValue("0.0001");
```

where rviz_manager_ is of type rviz::VisualizationManager.

---

Originally posted by [Julien Audet](https://answers.ros.org/users/40390/julien-audet/) with karma: 76 on 2020-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0